# Facial Expression Recognition on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am using OpenCV to develop an iPhone application, and I am using it to detect faces. Rather than detect the face as a whole, I would like to detect each of the smaller facial features (eyes, nose, ears, lips, etc.). Actually,I want to do something like this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjGw0Z_hziE&list=UUfqROL7_ETPYrckx8JoGIVQ)

How to use aam-opencv for iOS?

I searched on internet and I found this [link](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/)

But I don't know how to apply this on iOS. Please, can you help me about facial expression recognition?

Comment: hi you can check this link; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326477/how-to-access-video-camera-using-opencv-from-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression classification was my machine learning lesson project. I used opencv with C# to gather face images and train a recognizer then predict from the camera image.

My suggestion is not about ios but about aam part. In my project I used fisher face recognizer to classify expressions as follows :

1. User first smiles and press gather data button. Program detect face and use this as whole and add it to train image list. And in label list it labels it with 0.
2. After 5-10 images gathered with smile user stops it. Then another expression was used and face images gathered again.
3. After all expressions given, I had a train set like :

   face_1(smile) 0
    face_2(smile) 0
    face_3(sad)   1
    .
    .
    .

They are hold in arrays. Fisher Face Recognizer class is trained with this data.

Normally face recognizer is used to classify faces. But I used it to classify expressions by giving it different expressions. So intraclass variance will occur because of expressions in this case not because of different face since I used only my face for training.

So OpenCV ios port should have fisher face recognizer, you can use it for recognizing different expressions. It would be easier for you I guess. And besides AAM will only give you face landmarks. You need further training to train it for expressions.